# Finding feasible combinations in dataframe R / combinatorics

Tags: r, combinations, combinatorics

I have the following challenge:
dataframe with 218 observations (rows) and 218 variables (cols).
The values are either TRUE or FALSE.
Now i need to find combinations of variables (cols) that appear (TRUE) in at least 2 rows.

Here is a little example:

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(FALSE, nrow = 3, ncol = 5))
colnames(data) = paste("item_", 1:5, sep = "")
rownames(data) = paste("Process_", 1:3, sep = "")
data["Process_1",c("item_1","item_2","item_3")] = TRUE
data["Process_2",c("item_2","item_3")] = TRUE
data["Process_3",c("item_1","item_2","item_3","item_4","item_5")] = TRUE
```

For the example the feasible combinations (or the goal to find out) are the following combinations:

c1: item1,item2,item3

c2: item2,item3

c3: item1, item2

c4: item1, item3

Thank you very much for an answer or a hint :)

Cheers

Comment: Why is `c2` only == item2,item3 ?

Comment: c2 is a feasible combination (appears in at least 2 rows)

Comment: But why is c2 not item2,item3 ; item1item2 ; item1item3?

Comment: Holy moly, i see what you mean. I change the example according to your comment

Comment: Then I think @Wimpel's answer is what you're looking for!

Answer (score 2):

```
#all items that have TRUE in 2 or more rows
items <- names(which(colSums(data) >= 2))
# all possible combinations of 2 (or more) items
lapply(2:length(items), function(x) combn(items, x)
# [[1]]
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
# [1,] "item_1" "item_1" "item_2"
# [2,] "item_2" "item_3" "item_3"
# 
# [[2]]
#          [,1]    
# [1,] "item_1"
# [2,] "item_2"
# [3,] "item_3"
```